# React Native Search filter not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I am trying to implement react native search filter. I have my data array on the parent screen and I applied the search filter on the parent file and passed the filtered data array as props to the child screen. But no filter is happening. I am confused or no clue what wrong i am doing. I have the following codes:

**ParentScreen.js**

```
import SearchInput, { createFilter } from 'react-native-search-filter';
...
const KEYS_TO_FILTERS = ['title']

export default class ProductScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            items: API,
            searchTerm: '',
        }
    }

    searchUpdated(term) {
        this.setState({ searchTerm: term })
    }

    render() {

        const filteredItems = this.state.items.filter(createFilter(this.state.searchTerm, KEYS_TO_FILTERS))

        let cardGridWithBodyProps = {
            navigation: this.props.navigation,
            api: filteredItems,
            gridNumber: 2,
        }

        return (
            <Container>
                <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                    <View>
                        <Header>
                            <SearchInput 
                            onChangeText={(term) => { this.searchUpdated(term) }}
                            placeholder="Search"
                            />
                        </Header>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <CardGridWithBody {...cardGridWithBodyProps} />
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

**ChildScreen.js**

```
export default class CardGridWithBody extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            items: this.props.api
        }
    }

    renderGrid(gridArray) {
        return gridArray.map((row, rowIndex) => (
            <Row key={rowIndex}>
                {row.map((col, colIndex) => (this.renderColumn(col, rowIndex,colIndex)))}
            </Row>
        ));
    }

    renderColumn(colItem, rowIndex, colIndex) {
        return (
            <Col  key={colIndex}>
                <Text>{colItem.title}</Text>       
            </Col>
        )
    }

    renderContent() {
        let gridArray = this.state.items
        return this.renderGrid(gridArray)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.renderContent()
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving the data in state, access it directly from props. If you save it in state, you'll need to update it manually using lifecycle methods such as [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) or [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

```
renderContent = () => {
  let gridArray = this.props.api;
  return this.renderGrid(gridArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In parent screen convert

```
 searchUpdated(term) {
   this.setState({ searchTerm: term })
 }
```

to

```
 searchUpdated = term => {
      this.setState({ searchTerm: term })
    }
```

and in your child component you can do

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
      if (nextProps.api !== prevState.api) {
        return { api: nextProps.api };
      }
      return null;
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (
        this.state.items !==
        prevState.items
      ) {
        this.setState({ items: api });
      }
    }
```

Comment: could you show the result of `console.log(filteredItems)` and `console.log(items)` to find if the issue is with not being passed or something else from parent screen

Comment: yes i console.log(this.state.items) in childscreen as i am passing filteredItems props  from the parentscreen and it shows the items

Comment: could you paste the some result of `console.log(filteredItems)` and `console.log(items)` and `console.log(searchTerm)` here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194357/discussion-between-bhupati-and-wahidsherief).